# How to print unicode to both terminal and file redirect

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I read everything there is to read about Unicode, UTF-8, encoding/decoding and everything, but I still strugle.

I made a short example snippet to illustrate my problem.

I want to print the string 'Geïrriteerd' just like it is written here. I need to use the following code to let it print properly to a file if I run it with a redirect to a file, like 'Test.py > output'

```
# coding=utf-8
import codecs
import sys

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('UTF-8')(sys.stdout)

print u'Geïrriteerd'
```

But if I do NOT redirect, the code above prints 'Ge├»rriteerd' to the terminal.
If I remove the 'codecs.getwriter' line, it prints fine again to the terminal but will print 'Ge├»rriteerd' to the file.

How can I get this to print properly in both cases?

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 10. I know Python 3.x handles unicode better in general, but I can't use that in my project (yet) due to other dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminal is set up for [cp850](http://enwp.org/CP850) instead of UTF-8.

Run `chcp 65001`.

- http://enwp.org/Chcp_(command)
- http://enwp.org/Windows_code_page#List

Comment: Thank you, using this tip I solved it by adding one line:

> ret = subprocess.check_output('chcp 65001', shell=True)
'

Comment: The command is `chcp.com`; you don't need `shell=True` if you use the full name with the .com file extenson. FYI, the console's UTF-8 support is buggy. Changing the console input codepage to UTF-8 (65001) limits input to 7-bit ASCII in all versions of Windows (in Windows 10 a non-ASCII character is read as `'\0'`). For Python 2 and Windows 7 and earlier, setting the output codepage to 65001 will produce garbage output when printing non-ASCII to the console and even fail the write entirely if the console is using an OEM raster font.

Comment: It's better to use [win_unicode_console](https://pypi.org/project/win_unicode_console) in Python 2.x and Python 3.0-3.5 if you need to support Unicode in the Windows console.

Answer (score 2):

Since redirection is a shell operation, it makes sense to control the encoding using the shell as well.  Fortunately, Python provides an environment variable to  control the encoding.  Given `test.py`:

```
#!python2
# coding=utf-8
print u'Geïrriteerd'
```

To redirect to a file with a particular encoding, use:

```
C:\>set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
C:\>test >out.txt
```

Running the script normally with PYTHONIOENCODING undefined will use the encoding of the terminal (in my case `cp437`):

```
C:\>set PYTHONIOENCODING=
C:\>test
Geïrriteerd
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to "encode" your unicode first to write to file or display. You do not really need the codecs module. 
The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html) provide really good examples for working with unicode.

```
print type(u'Geïrriteerd')
print type(u'Geïrriteerd'.encode('utf-8'))
print u'Geïrriteerd'.encode('utf-8')

with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(u'Geïrriteerd'.encode('utf-8'))

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    print content

#If you want to use codecs still    
import codecs
with codecs.open("test.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(u'Geïrriteerd')

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    print content
```

Comment: Thank you. I also tried adding that .encode('utf-8') earlier, but it would still not work in my example above. Apparently the problem was my terminal was not using UTF-8.